# Magento 2.4.2: Updating Magento composer using the command "composer self-update -vvv" throws exception

Tags: magento2.4.2

I got an outdated extension from Klarna. In order to update this extension, I need to first update my composer. How do I go about updating it. Tried `self-update` command, and it didn't work.

Running the command composer self-update -vvv threw the following error. How to fix it?

```
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file /home/magento/.config/composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/magento/.config/composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Loading config file /home/magento/web/magento2.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/public_html/auth.json
Reading /home/magento/web/magento2.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/public_html/auth.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/magento/.config/composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /home/magento/web/magento2.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/public_html/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Plugin
activate magento plugin
Loading plugin Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin
Loading plugin Magento\ComposerRootUpdatePlugin\Plugin\PluginDefinition
Loading plugin Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPluginDelegator
Activating Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV1
Loading plugin Dealerdirect\Composer\Plugin\Installers\PHPCodeSniffer\Plugin
Running 1.9.3 (2020-02-04 12:58:49) with PHP 7.4.13 on Linux / 4.15.0-50-generic
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV1::onPreCommandRun
Downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions
Updating to version 2.1.5 (stable channel).
Downloading https://getcomposer.org/download/2.1.5/composer.phar.sig
   Downloading https://getcomposer.org/download/2.1.5/composer.phar
Downloading (100%)


  [ErrorException]
  rename(/home/magento/.cache/composer/composer-temp.phar,/usr/bin/composer):
   Permission denied


Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/SelfUpdateCommand.php:356
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a
 rename() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/SelfUpdateCommand.php:356
 Composer\Command\SelfUpdateCommand->setLocalPhar() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/SelfUpdateCommand.php:241
 Composer\Command\SelfUpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:267
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:106
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/bin/composer:61
 require() at /usr/bin/composer:24

self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--update-keys] [--stable] [--preview] [--snapshot] [--set-channel-only] [--] [<version>]
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What do you mean by it "didn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check composer version using below command from Magento root.

```
composer -vvv about
```

You should see somewhere below line in the output.

> Composer - Dependency Manager for PHP - version 2.x.x

If you see version 1.x.x then you might have to update composer by executing the `composer self-update -vvv`
then make sure that project is using the composer 2.x.x version again by executing `composer -vvv about`

Finally to update klarna you can choose any of the methods.

```
composer update klarna/* -vvv
```

OR

Remove completely klarna and then do re-install the full Klarna meta package.

```
composer remove klarna/m2-payments -vvv
composer require klarna/m2-payments -vvv
```

Please note, this will install/upgrade following modules.

- vendor/klarna/module-core
- vendor/klarna/module-kp
- vendor/klarna/module-kp-graph-ql
- vendor/klarna/module-onsitemessaging
- vendor/klarna/module-ordermanagement

Comment: Ran the command to find out what version my composer is. Below is the excerpt from the output. `Loading plugin Dealerdirect\Composer\Plugin\Installers\PHPCodeSniffer\Plugin
Running 1.9.3 (2020-02-04 12:58:49) with PHP 7.4.13 on Linux / 4.15.0-50-generic`
Is my composer version 1.9.3?

Comment: Yes you have to update composer to 2.x

Comment: Sandip, please have a look at the error messages posted above.

Comment: oh that is permission denied issue, Composer is installed as a root, so you probably did that as `root`, try with `sudo composer self-update -vvv`

Comment: ok,. will try and update

Comment: Hi, composer upgraded to version 2.1.5 successfully. I see there is nothing to push to the remote. I tried upgrading on the dev server. I thought it would change some files resulting in a need to push changed files to repository from the server. git status says my branch is up to date with origin.